# Attach tags or labels to stackdriver logs

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am using Standard AppEngine (Java) to develop a webservice. It seems that every request made to the service is automatically logged with stackdriver as a "request log", and each "request log" has multiple "application logs" attached to it .

I need to somehow pass in some additional information to be logged in stackdriver (like say the username of the person who made the request), and which can be later on extracted or scraped from stackdriver through a script.

I had 2 questions regarding this :

Is there anyway, I can attach this additional information to the request log ?

If I log the additional information as a normal log message which appears in the application log, is there a way to attach a distinguishing tag/label to the message, which will help me extract it easily and reliably ?  (rather than relying on finding patterns in the text of the message itself)

Comment: 1- Yes, you can add additional info as the application logs to the request log as it shows at: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/logs/; 2- Looks you can add the tag or label to the log: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/tasks/creating-logs#writing_log_entries

Answer (score 1):

1- Yes, you can add additional info as the application logs to the request log as it shows at: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/logs;

2- Looks you can add the tag or label to the log: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/tasks/creating-logs#writing_log_entries